# Ommitting a specific folder in htaccess redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Im trying to redirect a bunch of support files to a different support system except for any files that have the folder `software_updates` in them.  the following is the rule that I wrote.

```
RewriteRule ^/support/.*(?!software_updates).*$ newurl_location [NC,L,R=301]
```

this excludes `/support/software_updates/`  but not `/support/product/software_updates`   Im trying to exclude any URL that has software_updates anywhere in the URL after support.

Comment: Hey rocketdoctor, is this solved, or are you still struggling with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
RewriteRule ^support/(?!.*software_updates).*$ newurl_location [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/support/(?!.*software_updates) newurl_location [NC,L,R=301]
```

I don't have Apache handy to test it, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this and believe that it is what you're looking for (please note the changes in the `/` and the `.*` )

```
RewriteRule ^support/(?!.*?software_updates) newurl_location [NC,L,R=301]
```

You were nearly there.

First off, you don't need the initial `/`

You don't want `.*(?!software_updates).*`, because this will match `software_updates`. Why? The dot-star eats the whole string, then, at the end, you have the assertion that software_updates is not next. And of course this is true.